# Multimeter seems to be giving incorrect mA reading

Tags: multimeter, amperage

I'm measuring the current drawn from the negative battery terminal of my car battery.  I am not sure if the correct reading is 0.16 A or 1.6 mA. I tested with my multimeter on both 10 A and mA settings and posting pics you can see below:

[image: Ammeter reading 1]
[image: Ammeter reading 2]

Comment: Low on battery?

Comment: It does appear the QM1323 does have a fuse on 10A.  [User manual](https://www.techbrands.com/dbdocument/140291/qm1323_manual_3576.pdf#page=21)

Comment: The reading is 0.166A or 166mA.  The issue is:  Are you connecting the meter correctly to measure current?  You have to disconnect the lead from the battery and connect the meter in series to measure current.  This will exceed the 400mA range of mA scale.  Not sure if it will exceed 10A scale.  You never measure current unless you have some idea of the maximum current.

Answer (score 5):

You may have your meter set to the wrong range. The images in your post have been changed around a few times, but I've seen at least one showing a lead plugged into the 10A input, but the dial set to the mA range.

If you are using the 10A current input, you must set the meter to the 10A range. If you are using the general-purpose (V/Ω/Temp/Hz%/mA/µA) input, you must set the meter to the mA or µA range.

Comment: Or the OP is using the wrong socket for the mA range.  Should be using the right hand socket.

Comment: HI duskwuff, please see my link there are 2 pics in the one link on first i use 10A and second i use ma  -- link to 2 pics  https://imgur.com/a/xGHfFf5

Comment: ahh hanyhowie think you are right. d'oh - lemme go outside and check it out

Comment: @Alex: please upload the images to your post so that we don't have to follow links to understand your question. "mA", not "ma".

Comment: @AlexMikec  You will likely still get slightly different readings on the two ranges due to the different internal resistance of the multimeter in the different ranges.

Comment: thanks guys. the issue was the non-com testing lead needed to be plugged in the V OHM side (right side) . not the 10A side.  Thanks, couldn't see that label easily

Comment: @Transistor I added the images to the question, someone removed the second one.